# Careless downvoting?

Tags: discussion

The question under consideration is this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436368/result-of-this-comparison-a-b-c

After the question was answered, useful links provided and discussed by at least three members, it got downvoted. By three downvotes, without any explanation.

I fail to understand what is so bad about this question. Definitely being marked as a duplicate does not qualify a question to be a bad one. I performed a search before asking the question and the similar one did not show up.

Hopefully, we are not careless in downvoting.

Comment: I'm warning you - you may attract more down votes by posting here on meta. People are... like that. And no, I didn't down vote.

Comment: @Zizouz212:  You can't warn 'em like the rest of Meta will show 'em.

Comment: The other part of the downvote is the "research" bit.  The likely justification in a downvote there is, if you have a question that is a duplicate, you likely didn't do enough research.  It's not that I agree with that logic, necessarily, but that's an argument you may hear.

Comment: @Makoto You know what though, I feel for a lot of these people. I see people who have very reasonable questions, but get slammed with down votes under that argument. If "duplicates" are so inherently bad that we need to down vote them (and many of them to oblivion), why don't we just delete them on sight? While I don't agree with that view entirely, I've experienced it before. We're constantly told that dupes aren't bad, but the votes seem to perfectly contradict that.

Comment: @Zizouz212:  This is why I don't necessarily agree with that particular argument, since one may or may not fully understand what actual search terms to use to do the best possible job of research.   But since voting is fickle and unpredictable, I'm not really sure what we can do besides help users understand at least *why*.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I just carelessly downvoted and voted to close it !  XO - this is also known as the meta effect. That said, careless upvoting is much more harmful overall to the community in general.

Comment: @Zizouz212 At least in this case the expression itself is good enough (even for SO's imperfect search), but I agree in general.  I think one problem is that duplicates are supposed to be useful as signposts, but they rarely get upvoted when they redirect someone to another question with useful answers, so they cannot redeem themselves via their intended use.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It's quite rare for a duplicate to be a useful signpost.  Most duplicates aren't useful signposts as they simply aren't more discoverable than the canonical, or other existing duplicates.  You're correct that the rare useful signpost tends to not attract lots of upvotes, but just realize that this applies to fairly few closed duplicates.

Comment: @Servy Oh, I know that from experience.  My point is that we judge most posts on their score (and judge users mostly by the score of their posts), but because useful signposts don't get upvotes, score doesn't help differentiate a useful signpost from a useless duplicate.  (Besides the treatment of users that Zizouz brings up, if score was useful, we could probably turn on the Roomba for duplicates using the same criteria as for other closed posts, and take out a lot of garbage.)

Comment: Not a great question, as has been pointed out. Deserved a couple of downvotes. The -3 score you allude to in the question is totally reasonable, far from "careless." Probably doesn't merit a score of -12, but I'm guessing most of that is the Meta effect. Accusing people of being "careless" in downvoting is a bad approach. Voting is, by design, completely anonymous and entirely up to the user's discretion. There are few "standards," so it's nearly impossible to conclude an individual vote was "wrong." More to the point, there are many problems on SO, but a few downvotes are not among them.

Comment: The easiest way to get a variable ton of downvotes on your question is by whining about downvotes on meta. Its called the "meta effect" and you got hit by it.

Comment: Q: what happens when I write bad code?  A: don't write bad code.  It is never very clear what it takes to get an SO user to stop writing bad code.  Heaven forbid that it gets upvoted and makes another programmer think it is a good idea.   So a downvote is a pretty decent way to signal that it is not useful to do this.  Very much the opposite of "careless", the voter cared.

Comment: I looked at the question to see if it warranted downvoting, but I had already downvoted it.  The title screamed 'duplicate' and and 'academic code tht would be classed as garbage anywhere outside homework or an exam'.   It's in the same class as 'i++ + ++i', and got the same attention:(

Comment: I take extra care over good questions.  Stuff like erroneous/misleading boolean comparison expressions just gets thrown out with the trash.  It's been gone over, and over, and over, again and again on SO.  It's of zero or negative help for future visitors unless, possibly, they want a good choice of canned homework answers.

Comment: 'I performed a search before asking the question and the similar one did not show up.' - OK, please tell us which engines and what search criteria you used.

Comment: ' I see people who have very reasonable questions, but get slammed with down votes under that argument.' - WHAT!?   Reasonable to whom?  People post such questions without searching for web info and SO duplicates because that is work that they would rather someone else did for free.  It might sound good to the poster, it might sound good to you, it sounds like a disrepectful, immoral abuse to me.

Comment: If you tell us, here on meta, which engines and what search criteria you used, they are sane and they don't come up with useful answers to your question, I will apologize for my erroneous, careless conclusions, remove my downvote and vote to re-open your question:)

Comment: Search strings etc, please.....?

Comment: I can faintly hear the sounds of wind-blown sand and tumbleweed...

Comment: The search string in Google I used was, "if (a>b>c) c code" and the nearest that came up was, http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?513365-if(a-b-c). I read the whole post and the answers were not very definite. Then I thought that SO will be a better forum to ask. And no, I was not looking for a HW answer. The question was set by some paper setter in some test that came across me, and I was fully puzzled (we always see something like `a < b && b <c`, don't we? But that?!!!) and wanted to learn the explanation. I mentioned the point of another test in a comment to the original post.

Comment: How did you miss this thread: 'http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?513365-if%28a-b-c%29' which Google lists above your PHP link whjen using your search string, and actually contains C code?

Comment: @MartinJames The link you have provided is the same mentioned in my comment. Are we missing something here?

Answer (score 17):

I searched for [`[c] "a < b < c" is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+%22a+%3C+b+%3C+c%22+is%3Aq) and found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880467/why-does-a-b-c-inside-if-statement-in-c-not-work) dup-closed to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961643/usage-of-greater-than-less-than-operators), then immediately above your question in the search results, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219809/a-b-c-operators-in-c) which is dup-closed to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878632/compound-condition-in-c-if-0-0-a-1-0)... and that's without using any words like "comparison" or "less than"  in the search, which would probably turn up more equivalent questions.

I suspect you were downvoted because readers felt you didn't perform sufficient research before asking, and yet another duplicate is not likely to be a useful signpost for future searches.

Comment: I want to know what engine/s and search criteria/strings the OP used so as to come up with nothng useful.

Comment: @MartinJames Please see my comment to the original question.

Answer (score 7):

You have three questions, including a rather broad question, which makes your post:

- Too broad
- A duplicate for other reasons

> But what is the explanation behind this? Is it something like the following?

The first question is probably going to attract a long answer which might be coming from an official site for that particular language. Now if you ask whether the answer to the previous question is something like you described, that makes the question even worse. These two questions can be easily searched with Google.

> But is it mandatory for a truth value to be evaluated to 1? What happens when we assume a truth value to be any non-zero value rather than 1? What if in the above case, some intermediate result was true? How do we decide in the above case when a = 1, b = 5 and c = 10?

You had two already... now four more!? This is insane and definitely means you need to revisit the Help Center. Six questions is definitely way too broad and the quality of the questions themselves is rather low and subjective to opinion and debate/discussion. The questions you ask seems to also be easily Googled or tested by yourself.

So the reason for the downvotes will be:

- Way. Too. Broad. - Six questions is way too much
- Quality of questions - The questions can be answered by testing them yourself and/or using Google
- Is an easily found duplicate - Shows you have not invested research effort

Comment: Yes, definitely I could test and actually I did test. I used gcc compiler in Linux. But I wanted to find out whether other compilers will behave in the same manner and what is the general principle in a case like this.

Comment: But is being a duplicate such a big sin?